# In TextMate (or Sublime) how can I get the path relative my project directory?

Tags: textmate, textmate2

I've got the absolute path available in commands via `$TM_FILEPATH`. How can I write a command that gives me a relative path, specifically i'd like to copy this path to enable sharing and ease some git/bash operations?

Answer (score 1):

`pbcopy` will place a string onto your clipboard. From there, you just need to do some detect and replacement.

Start with the standard bash Command TextMate boilerplate:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
[[ -f "${TM_SUPPORT_PATH}/lib/bash_init.sh" ]] && . "${TM_SUPPORT_PATH}/lib/bash_init.sh"
```

Then check if the $TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY exists:

```
if [ -z ${TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY+x} ]; then
```

If not, copy the full path:

```
  echo -n "$TM_FILEPATH" | pbcopy
  echo "$TM_FILEPATH"'\n Absolute path copied to clipboard'
```

If so replace the project path in the file path, and copy;

```
else
  TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY="$TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY/"
  echo -n "${TM_FILEPATH#$TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY}" | pbcopy
  echo "${TM_FILEPATH#$TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY}"'\n Project relative path copied to clipboard.'
fi;
```

Please see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/loadedsith/0a2143717427eae2271d9e834129fb0b) incase of updates.